# Why can I continue to use the overridden structure even if I redefine the structure as typedef and annotate the typedef line?

Tags: c++, struct

Why can I continue to use the overridden structure even if I redefine the structure as typedef and annotate the typedef line?

```
#include <iostream>

#define MAZE_SIZE 21
#define MENU_H_SIZE 30
#define MENU_V_SIZE 120

using namespace std;

char strMaze[MAZE_SIZE][MAZE_SIZE] = {};

struct _tagPlayerPos
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

//typedef _tagPlayerPos POINT;   <- here
//typedef _tagPlayerPos* PPOINT; <- here


POINT tPlayerPos;
POINT tStartPos;
POINT tEndPos;

int main()
{
    setMaze(strMaze, &tPlayerPos, &tStartPos, &tEndPos
}
void setMaze(char Maze[MAZE_SIZE][MAZE_SIZE], PPOINT pPlayerPos, PPOINT pStartPos, 
PPOINT pEndPos)
{
    pStartPos->x = 1;
    pStartPos->y = 0;

    pEndPos->x = 18;
    pEndPos->y = 19;

    *pPlayerPos = *pStartPos;

    strcpy_s(Maze[0],       "02000000000000000000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[1],       "01111110001100000000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[2],       "00000011111000110000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[3],       "00000010010100100000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[4],       "00000110011111100000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[5],       "00000100000100000000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[6],       "00000100000111000000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[7],       "00011111000001000000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[8],       "00010001111100000000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[9],       "00010000001000000000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[10],      "01111000001111000000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[11],      "00001000000100000000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[12],      "00011000000111111100");
    strcpy_s(Maze[13],      "00010000001100000100");
    strcpy_s(Maze[14],      "00011111000000001100");
    strcpy_s(Maze[15],      "00000001000000001000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[16],      "00011101000111111000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[17],      "00000101000000000000");
    strcpy_s(Maze[18],      "00000111111111111110");
    strcpy_s(Maze[19],      "00000000000000000030");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can I continue to use the overridden structure even if I redefine the structure as typedef and annotate the typedef line?

You can't, the compiler doesn't know those names, you must be missing something, maybe you have these typedefs in other files included in main, it's hard to say, the only thing that is certain, is that the code you show alone will never compile as you can confirm in [this online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3ETBISlrdvEl2bPp).

In any case, in C++ you don't need to use typedef for the structure, you can just declare the structure like so:

```
struct POINT
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

And use it, no `struct` keyword is needed to declare a variable o type `POINT`.

```
POINT tPlayerPos;
POINT tStartPos;
POINT tEndPos;
```

Another thing to note is that *"overridden"* is probably not what you meant, the [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) keyword has a different meaning.

I also don't see any redefinition of the `struct` it in your code.

Comment: @Meggii, any time.